# 404 error when using spring to display jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, http-status-code-404

the url that is being clicked in the home is

```
<a href="\Assignment2\breweries\edit?id=${brewerie.id}">Edit</a>
```

the method its accessing in the controller is

```
@GetMapping("/edit")
public ModelAndView editBrewery(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
    return new ModelAndView("/editBrewery", "brewery", service.getBrewereriesID(id));
}
```

its not getting into the return in the @GetMapping  method in the controller, i put a break point at the return and it goes into the 404 before it gets to the breakpoint

the utput that the tomcat console is giving is

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Assignment2/breweries/edit] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `<a href="edit?id=${brewerie.id}">Edit</a>` (without the previous url parts).